# R ggplot add total labels to violin plots just above the base of the plot window

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text, violin-plot

I would like to add the total labels of another variable to some ranked violin plots, with the label or text just below the maximum of the plot window.  By hacking other bits of code I've found I've managed to get the labels to plot in a line but cannot work out how to move them to the top ... looking for something like a y-value of 8 ... I suppose I edit iris_summary's Sepal.Length values to 8 but is there another 'ggplot' way to change the plotting location of the plotted text?

```
iris_summary <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarize(sum_width = sum(Sepal.Width)) %>% 
  mutate(Sepal.Length = median(iris$Sepal.Length))

ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = reorder(Species, Sepal.Length, FUN = median), y = Sepal.Length, 
                        fill = Species)) +
  geom_violin() +
  geom_text(data = iris_summary, aes(label = sum_width), hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0, 
            position = position_nudge(y = -0.2), size = 5)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73696282/automatically-put-annotations-above-the-violin-plots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```r
ggplot(data = iris, 
       aes(x = reorder(Species, Sepal.Length, FUN = median), Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_violin(aes(fill = Species)) +
  geom_text(data = iris_summary, 
            aes(y = max(iris$Sepal.Length), label = sum_width),
            hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0, 
            position = position_nudge(y = 0.25), size = 5) +
  labs(x = "Species") +
  lims(y = c(4.1, 8.5)) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If the violin plot 'overlaps' the max iris$Sepal.Length, you could also use the max density of iris$Sepal.Length (places the labels a little bit higher), e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris_summary <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarize(sum_width = sum(Sepal.Width)) %>% 
  mutate(Sepal.Length = median(iris$Sepal.Length))

ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = reorder(Species, Sepal.Length, FUN = median), y = Sepal.Length, 
                        fill = Species)) +
  geom_violin() +
  geom_text(data = iris_summary,
            aes(label = sum_width,
                y = max(density(iris$Sepal.Length)[[1]])),
            hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0, size = 5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>